# CPU 100% after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, linux, anaconda, linux-mint

After having problems with pip + jupyter I decided to use Anaconda. I installed the latest version and now my PC is working slower than a turtle.
It keeps freezing and freezing. I can't use my terminal alright. It takes 2 minutes to change directory.

I'm checking my System load and of CPU's is always 100%, sometimes 2 of them 100% but it happens that all 4 have 100% load.

What I'm doing just trying to search the web for this problem and I had to restart my PC 2 times already.

It all started after I installed Anaconda.

Is this common practice? What should I do?

Comment: This is not common

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.